# Mac Tower (2013) High Sierra cannot boot into recovery

Tags: macos, mac, recovery

My tower is stuck booting into recovery.. Recovery show the dark grey screen but never loads.    Internet recovery does not work (goes straight to finder). I need to enter recovery
so that I can run the csrutil command.  What can I do to recover recovery mode, ideally without wiping my main HD?

Comment: Would it be possible to see two screens - what the “straight to finder” looks like and also what a boot without any keys pressed stays at?

Comment: Identical. Both end up at normal osx finder.